# spark 2.4.4 number of cores failing while declaring in spark session

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I am facing really a weird problem with spark application resources. My spark **spark-defaults.conf** file looks like this.

```
spark.executor.memory            9486M
spark.executor.cores             4
```

And in my application code i am declaring no of cores greater than default.Like below

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "8g")\
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "6")\
    .appName(app_name)\
    .getOrCreate()
```

Spark submit looks like

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster main.py
```

My application fails with below error

```
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Sun Aug 16 13:02:27 +0000 2020
LogLength:22066
Log Contents:
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1159, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 50, in <module>
    .appName(app_name)\
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 375, in getOrCreate
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 136, in __init__
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 198, in _do_init
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 314, in _initialize_context
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1525, in __call__
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 336, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:45417)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 929, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1067, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:45417)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1592991612264_0475/container_1592991612264_0475_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 929, in _get_connection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque
```

Log file is very big, but this is relevant info.
Now, interesting thing is,when i reduce no of cores to below or equal to 4 , it works.I was in impression that spark give priority to app code while resource config.
Has anyone face such issue? please help me here.

My spark version:

```
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.4
      /_/
```

Comment: Why is this an issue?

Comment: Well, i am clueless here

Comment: You override the default config from your app, so as you expected.

Comment: but override is not working as explained above

Comment: How many cores and memories for the driver and executors?

Comment: (spark.executor.cores , '6'), (spark.executor.memory', '8g'),(spark.driver.memory', '2048M')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219906/discussion-between-mahesh-kalani-and-lamanus).

Comment: You should check the settings `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` and `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores` for your YARN cluster.

Comment: @mazaneicha, yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores =8,yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores = 128